# Rails: implement auditing of table insertions/updates

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, logging, transactions, audit

I am fairly new to ROR and am working on a cargo tracking project.
The idea is to log all changes to shipment location so that when users track their shipment with a tracking number they would see the current location and a history of locations passed.

I have a shipments table and a shipment_locations table.

1. Shipments

   ```
   +--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
   +--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | id                       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
   | start_address_id         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
   | end_address_id           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
   | transportation_agency_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
   | customer_id              | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
   | status_id                | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
   | cargo_id                 | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
   | tracking_number          | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
   | mode_of_transport_id     | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
   | expected_start_date      | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
   | actual_start_date        | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
   | expected_end_date        | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
   | actual_end_date          | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
   | created_at               | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | updated_at               | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | admin_user_id            | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
   +--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   ```
2. shipment_locations: (Location updates are done on this table, under (current_location))

   ```
   +------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
   +------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | id               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
   | shipment_id      | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
   | current_location | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
   | final_location   | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
   | created_at       | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | updated_at       | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   +------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   ```
3. Shipment_history (proposed)

   Fields:

   - id
   - shipment_id
   - current_location
   - created_at
   - updated_at

I would like to store all the updates from shipment_locations table to this history table so that users can get:

```
Time (Updated_at):----------------------------> Location:(current_location)
1/12/2012 11:30                                  222 John st.
1/12/2012 13:00                                  555 Paul st.
1/13/2012 07:30                                  final_location
```

How can this be achieved from the controllers so that only one update action saves to history table?

UPDATE:

I was able to get a shipment tracking log using this trigger, thanks vladr

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER `shipment_after_update`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `shipment_after_update` AFTER UPDATE on `shipments`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO cargo_transit_histories 
    (`shipment_id` , `current_location` , `final_location` , `updated_at` ) 
  VALUES 
    (NEW.id, NEW.current_location, NEW.final_location, NOW());
END$$

DELIMITER ;

Comment: You may want to also consider the pros and cons of (1) using database triggers, (2) *versioning* your tables instead of having a separate audit table

Comment: Thanks vladr i will do some research on using triggers looks like a cleaner way of doing this. But with triggers there should be a separate table right?

Comment: With triggers you do whatever you want inside the trigger. Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346367/object-versioning-in-rails-like-papertrail-but-individual-tables and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697456/versioning-of-models-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Appreciate your prompt replies, will report back after trying these options.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you right and if it is a good approach but i'll try. 
I suggest you to make shipment_history belong to shipment_locations.

So if shipment_history has shipment_locations_id you could use a after_update callback to set what you need.

ShipmentLocations.model:

```
      #your other code
    after_update :track_changes_in_history

    def track_changes_in_history 
           @shipment_history=Shipment_history.where(:shipment_locations_id=>self.id).first_or_create!
@shipment_history.current_location = self.current_location
#so on
     end
```

But here with your model attributes I don't see the way to show its state in time. For that you'd probably better set separate for example `Map location:string` model, which belongs to all of other model by has_many declaration, and than you can show it state in history, by ordering locations, which belongs to this shipment.